# PayPal-NET-SDK GetTransaction from a sale on eBay

Tags: c#, api, paypal, sdk

I was trying to get the paypal transaction's details from an eBay sale. I'm using Paypal-NET-SDK built on PayPal's REST APIs.

Here is the code:

```
Dictionary<string, string> sdkConfig = new Dictionary<string, string>();
sdkConfig.Add("mode", "sandbox");
string accessToken = new OAuthTokenCredential(clientID, secret, sdkConfig).GetAccessToken();  

string transactionID = "98395731SM1933421";
APIContext apiContext = new APIContext(accessToken);
apiContext.Config = sdkConfig;
Sale sale = Sale.Get(apiContext, transactionID );
```

But I'm getting this error:
The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.

And this is the response:

```
{"name":"INVALID_RESOURCE_ID","message":"The requested resource ID was not found","information_link":"https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#INVALID_RESOURCE_ID","debug_id":"8a0a9ae305a35"}
```

It looks like I have to use another transaction ID, but this is the transaction ID I'm getting from the eBay API, and also when I enter into my account in paypal this is the transaction ID I'm seeing.

I want to know if I can use this API to get this transaction's details, if not, any suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Transaction IDs from PayPal's REST APIs and from PayPal's classic APIs are completely unrelated. eBay uses PayPal classic transaction IDs.

Or to put it another way: you cannot use PayPal's REST APIs with eBay transactions. Use PayPal's classic APIs, namely GetTransactionDetails.

Comment: Thank you for your answer geewiz, do you know about any .NET SDK for the classic APIs?

Comment: I cant find any example of how to call a classic API method in c#

Comment: @Joan haven't used Classic SDK in years, but it's [here](http://paypal.github.io/sdk/#merchant). I believe [this sample](https://github.com/paypal/merchant-sdk-dotnet/blob/master/Samples/PayPalAPISample/APICalls/GetTransactionDetails.aspx.cs) is what you are looking for. Hth...